# reset password in custom membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i just want to reset password using mvc 4 c# 
FYI: i am using my own custom authentication and authorization ,
i know that the best way is to send link for reset password ,
i just need article or code snippet apply this without membership,
i want to know how to make link expire? and how to generate unique link? and what is token ? and the use of token in rest password?

FYI:when i am build my own authorize system i just override AuthorizeCore function like this

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
}
```

is there any functions like AuthorizeCore to confirm account or change password can override ?
appreciate help thanks

Comment: you can use UserName in your link...username is unique  or UserName+Now DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting up the problem":

**Generate a GUID to create a unique link**
I like links that are not recognizable by the user; your best candidate is probably a random number or a GUID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).

```
System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("P"));
```

**Persist the username + expiry time with the GUID**
Either in memory or in your database, store the guid, the username and the timeout data. You do not expose this data to the outside

**Reset the password**
Your user clicks ",,/reset&guid=3432432. You retrieve the data in your database and the username, the timeout to the guid provided and reset the password (or not)

Comment: thanks Pleun i just want to know if i am using 
WebSecurity.ResetPassword(ReturnToken,Password) function do ?
here is a function generate token
   var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.UserName)
i just want to know how to add expiration date to this token?